# How do I left align a line in the title of PlantUML

Tags: plantuml

How do I left align a line in the title of PlantUML?

```
@startuml
title
SomeTitle . SomeTitle . SomeTitle . SomeTitle .
<font size=10> Want this left aligned</font>

endtitle

Alice -> Bob: Hello
@enduml
```

http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/SoWkIImgAStDuIh9BCb9vGhEpqqD0R4Kz1I8O7FPfENdbIWKPrQbsXeQs2c49m9v9HcPnGevgMab2eavcUbvgIas-Y1LTbnSgNaf46ku77CoarCLTEqKdFAJh1GyKdDoyhaSWD90bm00

I have tried

```
<font align:left>X</font>
<font text-align:left>Y</font>
```

I also tried adding `left`  to the `title` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PlantUML has GraphViz as a rendering engine. It supports `\l` and `\r` for left and right aligned:

```
@startuml
title SomeTitle . SomeTitle . SomeTitle . SomeTitle .\l<font size=10>Want this left aligned</font>

Alice -> Bob: Hello
@enduml
```

[image: PlantUML image]